# How can i fix my code to ignore the spaces when recognizing special characters in a string?

Tags: python, string, special-characters, isalpha

I've got this method to recognize if there are any special characters in a given string, and it works just fine when the string is one word only such as `'h3llo'`, it will return `True` (**there are special characters inside my string**), but when i add spaces to it (which is what has me struggling because of what i need the code for) it returns True even when there are no special characters in it at all, such as `hello how are you`, it will return `True`, because of the spaces. I need to fix my method to ignore the spaces, but I've ran out of ideas. I'd appreciate some help!! Thanks in advance :)

This is my function:

```py
def has_spchar(inputString):
    return any(not char.isalnum() for char in inputString)
```

Comment: Well, can you think of a logical rule that tells you whether a given character is special, taking into account the spaces? What happens if you substitute that rule in for the `not char.isalnum()` part? (Hint: do you know how to check whether a character is a space? Do you understand how `and` and `or` work?) "I've ran out of ideas" Well, *what ideas did you have so far*? What happened when you tried them?

Comment: Thanksss to you too!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def has_spchar(inputString):
    return any(not (char.isalnum() or char.isspace()) for char in inputString)
```

It might be more efficient, clearer, and easier to modify if you create a `set` of the characters that are not special and test against that.

Comment: Thankss i knew i had to do something like this but didn't know abt the isspace() method. thank you so much :)

Comment: @ronny just be aware `isspace` catches more than just spaces, things like `'\n'` are considered spaces too.